# Can't delete an object when using a different database connection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I have a table

[image]

When I delete, I kept getting

[image]

> Note : I connected to a specific database driver `babies` with a table name `babySettings`

I don't know why I can't delete this :

```
public function destroy($id)
{

    $inputs  = Request::all();
    $baby    = DB::connection('babies')->table("babySettings")->find($id);
    $oldBaby = $baby;

    $deleteLock = [1,2,3];


    if(in_array((int)$id,$deleteLock)) {
        return Redirect::to('/baby') ->with('error', 'F* off');
    }

    if($baby){

        $logs   = DB::connection('babies')->table("babyLogs")->where('babyId',$id)->get();
        
        if(count($logs) > 0){
            foreach ($logs as $log) {
                $log->delete(); 
            }

        }

        $baby->delete();    

    } 

    return Redirect::to($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ->with('success', $oldBaby->babyName . ' + (' . count($logs) . ') removed!');

}
```

Did I do something wrong ?

If I dd out the $baby, I seem to get it

```
{#501 ▼
  +"id": 93
  +"status": 0
  +"uuid": "28753a43-2c30-4ce0-b4db-b177a8d6ae3c"
  +"name": "John Doe"
  +"email": "jdoe@gg.com"
  +"password": "$2y$10$oIq.SwurET3JBLuXgSJwLOUAZADQTjOTcnPKijV1EmUNBnsreoLvm"
  +"phone": ""
  +"address": ""
  +"babyName": "tyty"
  +"babyDob": "2021-04-18"
  +"verifyCode": "EnQoq8cheWGL4a37wyhtaK6fevJRZGLHoCyZ&t=1618743364"
  +"babyProfilePath": "https://i.imgur.com/DF8G7HS.png"
  +"babyBgPath": null
  +"adminCode": "x895Gq"
  +"readOnlyCode": "Z1EVdd"
  +"created_at": "2021-04-18 07:56:04"
  +"updated_at": "2021-04-18 07:56:04"
  +"feedingInterval": 2
  +"displayMode": 2
  +"imgUrAlbumId": null
}
```

Comment: Either this line didnt work `$baby    = DB::connection('babies')->table("babySettings")->find($id);` or what it returns is not what you think

Comment: I showed you the dd result of it. Does it look ok ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly DB returns a Collection of stdClass, and it does not have the delete method available.

Comment: @MateusJunges Yes I assumed that, but not having Laravel'ed for a couple of years I just generalised my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `DB`, it returs a collection of s`stdClass` objects.

The delete function isn't available for stdClass objects. You can use DB to delete your records:

```php
$logs = DB::connection('babies')->table("babyLogs")->where('babyId',$id)->get();

foreach ($logs as $log) {
    DB::connection('babies')->table('babyLogs')->where('id', $log->id)->delete();
}
```

Or, you can delete all with one query:

```php
DB::connection('babies')->table("babyLogs")->where('babyId',$id)->delete();
```

The `baby` is also `stdClass`, so, you have to delete it using query builder or eloquent:

```php
DB::connection('babies')->table("babySettings")->where('id', $id)->delete();
```

Comment: the babyLog is not a problem, the baby is the problem. :)

Comment: But I see where is the isse is now when seeing your answer.

Comment: To delete the baby you also need to use DB. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the Eloquent ORM by fetching a record using the DB::table method.  The record you are fetching is just a standard object, so it has no method available to delete.

You could use Eloquent to fetch the record in a more structured way by binding it to an model, or you can use the DB helpers (Query Builder) to delete the record the same way you are fetching it.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#delete-statements

Comment: I know how to delete() , but this one is a rare case one.

Comment: Why is this a rare case?  You're calling delete on a stdClass object which has no methods.